# Objects in list get removed when applying Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation

Tags: c#, list, monogame, path-finding

I didn't know how to formulate the question title any better without getting too descriptive, I'm sorry in advance...

Anyhow, my problem is the following.

I have a List NodeList, and a secondary List named Unvisited.

I use the Method GetPath on the Unvisited list (it's an implementation of Dijkstra's Pathfidning Algorithm). But for some weird reason when I draw the texture stored in the Nodes in the NodeList some of the nodes (particularly, the nodes used to trace a path between) get removed.

I am looking for an explanation why the Nodes get removed from the NodeList even when I clearly set Unvisited equal NodeList...

EDIT: If there is any code that is missing to understand the problem, ask and I will edit!

Relevant Code:

```
public class Hotel
{
    public List<Node> nodeList;

        //constructor loadscontent and initialises list, ommitted here.

    public void BuildHotel(ContentManager content)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            GuestRoom temp = new GuestRoom(100 + i, content, new Point(64 + (i * 64), 128), new Point(2, 1));
            nodeList.Add(new Node(temp, new Point(64 + (i * 64), 128)));
        }

        // add edges between some nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            AddEdge(nodeList[i].Room.RoomId, nodeList[i + 1].Room.RoomId, 2);
        }

        guest = new Guest(content);
        guest.Setpath(100, 104, nodeList);
    }


}
class PathFinding
{
    public List<Node> Unvisited;
    public List<Node> Visited;
    private Stack<Node> _temp = new Stack<Node>();

    public Stack<Node> GetPath(int startroom, int finalroom, List<Node> nodeList)
    {
        Unvisited = nodeList;
        Node startNode = Unvisited.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Room.RoomId == startroom);
        Node finalNode = Unvisited.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Room.RoomId == finalroom);

        if (startNode == null || finalNode == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("At least one of the nodes does not exist");
            return null;
        }

        startNode.Distance = 0;

        Node currentNode = startNode;

        while (!IsVisited(currentNode, finalNode))
        {
            currentNode = Unvisited.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Distance < r.Distance ? l : r);
        }

        //reverse nodes in queue
        Queue<Node> reversedqueue = MakePath(startNode, currentNode, finalNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < MakePath(startNode, currentNode, finalNode).Count; i++)
        {
            _temp.Push(reversedqueue.Dequeue());
        }
        return _temp;
    }
}

public class SimulationScreen : Screen
{
    private Hotel hotel;
    //.. other methods ommited.
    public override void Activate(bool instancePreserved)
    {
        if (!instancePreserved)
        {
            if (_content == null)
                _content = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Game.Services, "Content");

            ScreenManager.Game.ResetElapsedTime();
        }
        hotel = new Hotel(_content);
    }
}
```

[image: Visual Representation on the bug]
Visual Representation on the bug
[image: Without the pathfinder turned on]
Without the pathfinder turned on

Comment: "But for some weird reason when I draw the texture stored in the Nodes in the NodeList some of the nodes (particularly, the nodes used to trace a path between)." I think you're missing the end of that sentence; "get removed" perhaps?

Comment: List every place in the program where a node is removed.  One of them is removing from the wrong list.  Now figure out which one.

Comment: You might consider rewriting your algorithm to use immutable lists; that's a powerful technique for ensuring that you never have a bug caused by a list mutation; there are no list mutations.

Comment: I didn't finish that sentence indeed, my brain went on too fast haha. As for Eric's reply, I posted every place in my code that removes a Node from the List, only the algorithm does list mutations. I have no experience with an immutable list, still a student in my second year so I guess it'll be taught later in the curriculum

Comment: We probably need to see where the Hotel class is used. There is nothing in the code shown that removes from NodeList.

Comment: That's the problem, I have looked through my entire solution and there is not a single place where the nodes get removed from the `NodeList` ._. any removal from the list is from the `Unvisited` list... :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
Unvisited = nodeList;
```

> That's the problem, I have looked through my entire solution and there is not a single place where the nodes get removed from the NodeList ._. any removal from the list is from the Unvisited list... :s

After that assignment, any removal from the Unvisited list removes from the nodeList. List is a reference type, so when you change its value with an assignment you're really changing which object it refers to. Unvisited and nodeList both refer to the same object after this. To avoid this, instantiate a new List using the old one rather than assigning both lists to the same reference:

```
Unvisited = new List<Node>(nodeList);
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you! That's exactly what the problem was! I indeed never initialised the list on it's own thus I deleted from `NodeList`. Thank you for the explanation too :)